# Open a link from popup pdf in a new browser window

Tags: javascript

I am openning one popup window using window.open .Now that popup contains a pdf.If there is any link in that pdf (like www.google.com) clicking the link is openning the site inside the popup only.How to make this link open in a new browser window ? I have created the pdf using corda.

Comment: Is that link accessible to call in a function?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for opening a new window when the user click on a link?

if so here is how:

```
<a href='link.pdf' target='_blank'>Read Me</a>
```

See the list of values the [Target Attribute](http://www1.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) can take :)

Comment: No my problem is if the PDF opens in a new window and the PDF contain active links like www.google.com ,on click of www.goole.com the site should open in a new browser.I have a html where user enters the link and then that HTML gets converted to PDF using corda.